timeout error when i apply my changes in terraform
I'm facing a timeout error when I run terraform apply. Here’s what I’m trying to do:
I want to host my app on an Ubuntu server. To do this, I’m creating all the required resources using Terraform. However, when I run terraform apply, I encounter the following error
│ timeout - last error: dial tcp 3.81.61.64:22: i/o timeout
code:
https://privatebin.net/?78a142719701b8ed#6dU3aLZdL9DEBBNEPbYmAokEbQT71ZaH17yJS8nTUvMx
Error: file provisioner error

  with aws_instance.myinstance,
  on main.tf line 97, in resource "aws_instance" "myinstance":
  97:     provisioner "file" {

timeout - last error: dial tcp 2.21.32.222: i/o timeout

# Specify the AWS provider and region for deploying the resources
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1" # AWS region where resources will be created
}

# Create an AWS key pair to allow SSH access to EC2 instances
resource "aws_key_pair" "keyone" {
  key_name   = "my-key"  # Name of the key pair
  public_key = file("C:/Users/.ssh/xsec.pub") # Path to the public key file
}

# Create a VPC (Virtual Private Cloud)
resource "aws_vpc" "cityvpc" {
  cidr_block           = var.cidr # CIDR block for the VPC, passed via a variable
  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
}

# Create a subnet within the VPC
resource "aws_subnet" "citysub" {
  cidr_block = var.cidr_256 # Subnet CIDR block, passed via a variable
  vpc_id     = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "citysub"
  }
}

# Create an internet gateway to allow public internet access
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "citygate" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "citygate"
  }
}

# Create a route table to define routing rules
resource "aws_route_table" "cityroute" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id
  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.citygate.id
  }
}

# Associate the route table with the subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "cityrouteassn" {
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.cityroute.id
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.citysub.id
}

# Create a security group in the VPC
resource "aws_security_group" "citysecurity" {
  name        = "TLS Allow"
  description = "Allow TLS traffic"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.cityvpc.id
}

# Ingress rule to allow HTTP traffic (port 80)
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allowHTTP" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.citysecurity.id
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port         = 80
  to_port           = 80
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
}

# Ingress rule to allow SSH traffic (port 22)
resource "aws_vpc_security_group_ingress_rule" "allowSSH" {
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.citysecurity.id
  cidr_ipv4         = "0.0.0.0/0"
  from_port         = 22
  to_port           = 22
  ip_protocol       = "tcp"
}

# Create an EC2 instance
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ami                          = "ami-0e2c8caa4b6378d8c"
  instance_type                = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id                    = aws_subnet.citysub.id
  key_name                     = aws_key_pair.keyone.id
  associate_public_ip_address  = true

  # SSH connection settings
  connection {
    type        = "ssh"
    user        = "admin"
    private_key = file("C:\\Users\\.ssh\\xsec")
    host        = self.public_ip
  }

  # Provisioner to copy a file
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "app.py"
    destination = "/home/admin/app.py"
  }

  # Provisioner to run remote commands
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo 'Hello from remote server'",
      "sudo apt-get update -y",
      "sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y"
    ]
  }
}


The most important detail of your question, the actual error message itself, which includes the fact that is is happening in a file provisioner, is only in the privatebin you linked to, and not in the actual question you posted. I have added that to the question for you, but PLEASE in the future include all relevant details in your actual StackOverflow post itself, and not in some off-site pastebin thing.

Using file provisioners and remote-exec provisioners on EC2 instances in Terraform is considered a bad practice and should only be used as a last resort. The problem being that the machine you are running Terraform on may not have SSH network access to the EC2 instance if the EC2 instance is in a private subnet, or it may just time out waiting for the instance to start up or something. A much more robust solution is to use EC2 user-data to provision files and run startup scripts.
The EC2 user-data feature actually uses cloud-init, which supports things like file creation, startup scripts, and more. There is a Terraform provider for creating cloud-init configs, which you can then pass to the EC2 instance's user-data field:
data "cloudinit_config" "my_user_data" {
  ... 
}

resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
   ...

   user_data = data.cloudinit_config.my_user_data.rendered
}

